# What is the correct syntax to execute a SQL Like statement with param using sql-template-tag?

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript

What is the correct synatx in order to perform a LIKE statement using sql-template-tag and with a param?

This is an example statement:

```
export function deleteTickets(ticketId: string) {
  const query = sql`DELETE FROM ticket.tickets WHERE tickets.uuid LIKE ${ticketId}%`;
  return execute(ticketDb, query);
}
```

However, the above statement throws an error stating `you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%' at line 1`

When I then try to wrap in quotes the param the and % like so, then it doesn't acknowledge the param, it replaces the param values as a ? so it won't delete the correct entry as it's looking for ? as ticketId.

```
export function deleteTickets(ticketId: string) {
  const query = sql`DELETE FROM ticket.tickets WHERE tickets.uuid LIKE '${ticketId}%'`;
  return execute(ticketDb, query);
}
```